# optimize performance when creating dataframe from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Data looks like this:

```
data = {"date": 20210606,
        "B": 11355,
        "C": 4,
        "ID": "ladygaga"}
```

I want to convert it to dataframe however each value needs to be a list therefore

```
data = {key: [item] for key, item in data.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

this is what I do, I want to optimize code as much as possible since this is going to be on production level API.

Comment: There's nothing really to optimize here. Is your data always a simple dict that you are making a dataframe with one row? Why do this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass dictionary to list like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([data])
print (df)
       date      B  C        ID
0  20210606  11355  4  ladygaga
```

Also your solution should be faster by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({key: [item] for key, item in data.items()})
```

Comment: running each solution with %%timeit, your last solution is faster by 8micro seconds(572 ->566) and your first soultion seems to be slower.

Comment: @haneulkim - ya, I hope hope second solution.